# NDK : Problems with VM aborting and Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm tring SpectrumWorx Melodify SDK from [LITTLE ENDIAN](http://www.littleendian.com/developers/),
but the problems really puzzle me these days.

When I was trying to use Melodify SDK by Activity not ANativeActivity, the problem occured.
From the doc API, we should setAppContext first, like codes below:

```
void    setAppContext (::ANativeActivity const &,::ndk_helper::JNIHelper const &)
void    setAppContext (::ANativeActivity const &)
void    setAppContext (::JavaVM &,::jobject activity,::jobject assetManager)
void    setAppContext (::JavaVM &,::jobject activity)
```

### So I start as this example.cpp:

```
#include "le/audioio/device.hpp"
#include "le/audioio/file.hpp"
#include "le/audioio/outputWaveFile.hpp"

#include "le/melodify/melodifyer.hpp"

#include "le/utility/entryPoint.hpp"
#include "le/utility/filesystem.hpp"
#include "le/utility/trace.hpp"
#include "le/utility/sleep.hpp"

#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "testjni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

static JavaVM *g_VM;

extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv*   env, jobject obj);
};

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return -1;
    g_VM = vm;
    LOGI("JNI INIT");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
   LOGI("JNI work !");

    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/ledemo/MainActivity");
    if (clazz == 0) {
        LOGI("FindClass error");
        return;
    }
    jmethodID javamethod = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "callFromCPP", "()V");
    if (javamethod == 0) {
        LOGI("GetMethodID error");
        return;
    }
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, javamethod);
    using namespace LE;
    LE::Utility::setAppContext(*g_VM, clazz);
    LOGI("setContext finish");
    }
```

### but the logcat error :

```
12-30 15:15:34.251: A/SpectrumWorx SDK assertion failure(8638): methodGetAssets (271)
12-30 15:15:34.251: A/libc(8638): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 8638 (.example.ledemo)**strong text**
```

### And I try this codes:

```
#include "le/audioio/device.hpp"
#include "le/audioio/file.hpp"
#include "le/audioio/outputWaveFile.hpp"

#include "le/melodify/melodifyer.hpp"

#include "le/utility/entryPoint.hpp"
#include "le/utility/filesystem.hpp"
#include "le/utility/trace.hpp"
#include "le/utility/sleep.hpp"

#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <assert.h>
// for native asset manager
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "testjni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

static JavaVM *g_VM;
static jobject gActivity;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env,         jobject obj);
};

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return -1;
    g_VM = vm;
    LOGI("JNI INIT");

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_javaCallJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    LOGI("JNI work !");

    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/ledemo/MainActivity");
    if (clazz == 0) {
        LOGI("FindClass error");
        return;
    }
    jmethodID javamethod = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "callFromCPP", "()V");
    if (javamethod == 0) {
        LOGI("GetMethodID error");
        return;
    }
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, javamethod);

    gActivity = (jobject)env->NewGlobalRef(clazz);

}

extern "C" void  Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_setJNI(JNIEnv* env, jclass         clazz, jobject assetManager)
{
    using namespace LE;
    LE::Utility::setAppContext(*g_VM, gActivity, assetManager);
    LOGI("setContext finish");
}
```

### And Here is my Java Codes:

```
package com.example.ledemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    static AssetManager assetManager;
    Activity activity;

    public native void javaCallJNI();
    public native void setJNI(AssetManager assetManager);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        assetManager = getAssets();

        Log.i("onCreate", "Native function begining");
        javaCallJNI();
        Log.i("onCreate", "Native function ending");

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            setJNI(assetManager);   
        }
    });
}

void callFromCPP() {
    Log.i("callFromCPP", "JNI can call JAVA !");
    return ;
}
```

### Problem still occured:

```
12-30 15:55:12.646: I/testjni(12862): JNI INIT
12-30 15:55:12.694: I/onCreate(12862): Native function begining
12-30 15:55:12.694: I/testjni(12862): JNI work !
12-30 15:55:12.694: I/callFromCPP(12862): JNI can call JAVA !
12-30 15:55:12.695: I/onCreate(12862): Native function ending

12-30 15:55:33.327: W/dalvikvm(12862): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
12-30 15:55:33.328: W/dalvikvm(12862):              in Lcom/example/ledemo/MainActivity;.setJNI:(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;)V (CallObjectMethodV)
12-30 15:55:33.328: W/dalvikvm(12862): Pending exception is:
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getFilesDir' signature='()Ljava/io/File;' in class Ljava/lang/Class;
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at com.example.ledemo.MainActivity.setJNI(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at com.example.ledemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 15:55:33.328: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.329: I/dalvikvm(12862): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
12-30 15:55:33.330: I/dalvikvm(12862):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x415a3a30 self=0x41592f10
12-30 15:55:33.330: I/dalvikvm(12862):   | sysTid=12862 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074337884
12-30 15:55:33.330: I/dalvikvm(12862):   | state=R schedstat=( 267627914 199014395 585 ) utm=19 stm=7 core=0
12-30 15:55:33.372: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
12-30 15:55:33.372: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #01  pc 0006118e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+53)
12-30 15:55:33.372: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #02  pc 00054aaa  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+329)
12-30 15:55:33.372: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #03  pc 00054b4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
12-30 15:55:33.372: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #04  pc 00038eba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #05  pc 00040f92  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #06  pc 0002b0f8  /data/app-lib/com.example.ledemo-2/liblittle-effect.so
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #07  pc 0002ad34  /data/app-lib/com.example.ledemo-2/liblittle-effect.so
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #08  pc 000066fe  /data/app-lib/com.example.ledemo-2/liblittle-effect.so     (Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_setJNI+13)
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #09  pc 0001e4d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-30 15:55:33.373: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #10  pc 0004ddf8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+499)
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #11  pc 00050190  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+171)
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #12  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #13  pc 0002b804  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #14  pc 000613ce  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+373)
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #15  pc 000692e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.374: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #16  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #17  pc 0002b804  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #18  pc 000610a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #19  pc 0004a0d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #20  pc 0004d126  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #21  pc 0004decc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+399)
12-30 15:55:33.375: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #22  pc 00000db6  /system/bin/app_process
12-30 15:55:33.376: I/dalvikvm(12862):   #23  pc 0001bd98  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+64)
12-30 15:55:33.376: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at com.example.ledemo.MainActivity.setJNI(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.376: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at com.example.ledemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
12-30 15:55:33.377: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
12-30 15:55:33.377: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
12-30 15:55:33.377: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-30 15:55:33.377: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-30 15:55:33.378: I/dalvikvm(12862):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 15:55:33.379: E/dalvikvm(12862): VM aborting
12-30 15:55:33.380: A/libc(12862): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 12862 (.example.ledemo)
```

I don't know how to deal with that, I have searched many ways but still can't find the right one. Really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is just creating a global reference to the loaded *class*:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/ledemo/MainActivity");

gActivity = (jobject)env->NewGlobalRef(clazz);
```

You're not creating an *instance of that class*, which is what `setAppContext` expects.

Your declaration of `setJNI` is also a bit incorrect. Instead of:

```
extern "C" void  Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_setJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jclass clazz,
    jobject assetManager)
```

it should be:

```
extern "C" void  Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_setJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject thiz,   // <-- note the difference here
    jobject assetManager)
```

The `jobject thiz` argument is a reference to the Java object on which the native method was invoked (i.e. your `MainActivity`). So you should be able to pass `thiz` as the second argument to `setAppContext` (I'm not sure if you need to create a global reference to it as well).

Comment: Yes, you right. I have used jobject thiz instead of jclass clazz, but the logcat would show error about can not find the method because of adding jobect assetManager. So I just do like this [Android ndk : Problem for call of Java method from c++ with jni](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584269/android-ndk-problem-for-call-of-java-method-from-c-with-jni?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: My main problem is to use `void    setAppContext (::JavaVM &,::jobject activity,::jobject assetManager)`; so I should put the right params avoiding the error like **VM aborting**

Comment: Well, in the Java code you've shown, the `setJNI` is non-static, so the second argument should be a `jobject` instead of a `jclass`. It's hard to say why that would give you an error without having seen the error message.

Comment: I try as you say.  
`extern "C" void  Java_com_example_ledemo_MainActivity_setJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject assetManager)
{
 using namespace LE;
 LE::Utility::setAppContext(*g_VM, gActivity, assetManager);

 LOGI("setContext finish");
}`   
but error still shows VM aborting,   
>12-30 18:01:04.882: W/dalvikvm(18671): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
>12-30 18:01:04.882: W/dalvikvm(18671): in Lcom/example/ledemo/MainActivity;.setJNI:(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;)V (CallObjectMethodV)`

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, you shouldn't pass `gActivity` to `setAppContext` because that's not a reference to an `Activity` object - it's a reference to your `MainActivity` _class_. Pass `thiz` to `setAppContext` instead.

Comment: I used thiz before but logcat shows the same. I have tried many ways to pass the activity, neither worked.I am really puzzled.

Comment: "JNI method called with exception pending" means something failed earlier, and the code ignored the exception and tried to make additional JNI calls.  You, or the library you're calling, needs to check for exceptions after making JNI calls that can throw, and either handle them or clear them.

Comment: I removed code for the global reference to the loaded class and use the jobject thiz in setJni method but problem still exists